# How to filter out conditions based on a group by in JPA?

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

I have a table like

```
| customer | profile | status | date    | 

| 1        | 1       | DONE   | mmddyy  |

| 1        | 1       | DONE   | mmddyy  |
```

In this case, I want to group by on the profile ID having max date. Profiles can be repeated. I've ruled out Java 8 streams as I have many conditions here.

I want to convert the following SQL into JPQL:

```
select customer, profile, status, max(date) 
from tbl 
group by profile, customer,status, date, column-k 
having count(profile)>0 and status='DONE';
```

Can someone tell how can I write this query in JPQL if it is correct in SQL? If I declare columns in `select` it is needed in group by as well and the query results are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want the most recent customer/profile combination that is done.

If so, the correct SQL is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.customer = t.customer and t2.profile = t.profile
               ) and
      t.status = 'DONE';
```

I don't know how to convert this to JPQL, but you might as well start with working SQL code.

Comment: Thank you this works! I'm assuming this can't be done with a group by and having clause in a simple manner.

Answer (score 0):

In your query `date column` not needed in `group by`  and `status='DONE'` should be added with `where clause`

```
select customer, profile, status, max(date) 
from tbl 
where status='DONE'
group by profile, customer,status,  
having count(profile)>0
```